# Какая разница между сравнительными союзами КАК и БУДТО?

Tags: значение-слов, союзы

**Болотников посмотрел на Николаса, будто на умственно отсталого** (Б. Акунин).

Почему автор в данном случае использовал союз БУДТО?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.**

**Ситуация такая:** Николас, магистр истории, приехал в Россию из Англии  за важным документом. Диалог между ним и русским талантливым историком:

— Господин директор сказал, что вам предлагали место в Стэнфорде, а вы отказались. Почему? Из патриотизма? – Какой к черту патриотизм. – Болотников посмотрел на Николаса, будто на умственно отсталого. – Я специалист по русской истории и палеографии. Все важные документы по моей специальности находятся в России, не в Стэнфорде.

Между изъяснительными союзами разница указана: КАК ― нейтральный союз, БУДТО имеет оттенок недостоверности. **Но чем отличаются эти союзы в сравнительных предложениях?**

Comment: Jasmin, может быть, стоит добавить метки _выбор слов_ и _союзы_?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, автору не нравилась двусмысленность в варианте с "как": этот вариант *допускает*, что второй персонаж и впрямь был умственно отсталым и что в дальнейшем такое может выясниться. Вариант с "будто" полностью исключает это (мол автор знает, что это не так).

Comment: Ситуация там немного другая (см.в дополнении). Но всё-таки вы считаете, что между союзами существует  семантическая разница  при сравнении, как и при изъяснении?  Но ведь ситуация в книге совершенно понятная, союз КАК там вполне бы был на месте. Есть ли  у союза БУДТО  какой-нибудь стилистический или семантический оттенок?

Comment: Если ситуация этого не требовала, то автор, возможно, хотел выразиться нестандартно. А может быть, хотел подчеркнуть, что ничего глупого первым персонажем сказано не было ("будто" поясняет позицию говорящего, а "как" звучит чисто описательно, нейтрально).

Answer (score 1):

1. Мне кажется, что в придаточном предложении сравнения, в котором использован союз **как**, указывается на сравнение как **на реальный факт** (сравнение с тем, что было или есть, с тем, что очевидно или возможно).

*Все лето лил дождь, **как** это бывает только осенью.*
(Вполне действительное явление.)

Николас может быть умственно отсталым? Вполне вероятно (а вдруг?).

2. Союз **будто** указывает на сравнение как на недостоверную, условную, **ирреальную возможность.**

*Все лето лил дождь, **будто** небо опрокинулось на землю.*
(Значение — как будто, словно. Небо опрокинуться не может — ситуация неестественна, символична, воображаема.)

Николас умственно отсталый? Нет. Автор это знает (просто слова собеседника вызвали такую нервную ассоциацию и соответствующий взгляд), поэтому он и использовал для сравнения союз "будто".

Comment: Не знаю, я начинаю думать, что эта фраза ( с нужным союзом) выражает чью-либо точку зрения: (1) автора,  (2)говорящего/думающего или (3) слушающего/воспринимающего..В данном случае это восприятие именно  героя (Николаса), который точно знает, что он не умственно отсталый, но понимает, что произвел такое впечатление. В общем, возможно, это такой художественный прием, элемент несобственно-прямой речи.

Comment: Поскольку это в авторской речи, то к автору и позиция относится (если это не пересказ от имени ещё кого-то), а персонажу с его эмоциями в тот момент могло и впрямь показаться, что собеседник "того".

Comment: В несобственной прямой речи автор отождествляет себя с героем.